# regular expression in Teradata query

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have below input strings:

string1:
xyx;;;;str1=P1:P2|str2=1/3|str3=s1:s2

string2:
mzn;;;;str1 = P3:P4 | str2 = 2/5

result expected:
for string1:
str1_val=P1:P2
str2_val=1/3

for string2:
str1_val=P3:P4
str2_val=2/5

I tried with
str1_val= REGEXP_SUBSTR('xyx;;;;str1=P1:P2|strt2=1/3|str3=s1:s2', '(?<=str1=)(.*?)(?=|)')  - working fine
str2_val=REGEXP_SUBSTR('xyx;;;;str1=P1:P2|str2=1/3|str3=s1:s2', '(?<=str2=)(.*?)(?=|)') - working fine

working fine for string1 but not working for string2.
Please help one  way which will work for both the case

Answer (score 0):

You need to add optional spaces, but the lookbehind only allows fixed length matches. But `\K` is similar, it resets the start of the match, i.e. *forget the previous match*:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'str1\s*=\s*\K([^|]+)')

\s*       = optional whitespace
\K        = reset start of match
([^|]+)   = any char but a |
```

See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/dv6M6k/1)